# How do I validate the Spell Selections in an Eldritch Knight Spell List?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, fighter, eldritch-knight

This is a direct follow-up to [this question for Sorcerers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131928/is-there-an-easy-way-to-validate-a-high-level-sorcerers-spell-list), which contains more context and examples of this problem.

For pregenerated high-level Eldritch Knights, it's important to make sure that their spell list is valid for a character of their level, but the process of taking a given spell list and evaluating "is this list correct for an Eldritch Knight of X level" is tedious and time consuming. So is there a table/rule that can be followed to easily make this determination?

Note: I'm following the format established by [my previous question for Bards](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131985/how-do-i-validate-the-spell-selections-in-a-bard-spell-list). The Meta for discussing this decision can be found [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8383/how-should-i-post-additional-tables-for-this-question-about-known-spells).

Answer (score 4):

This table is generated using the same methods that [Axoren used in their answer to the base question about Sorcerers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/131936/42386).

#### How to Use it

Like with Axoren's table, the way to use it is to read each column as permitting spells of that level or lower. So for example, a level 13 Eldritch Knight can know:

- 2 Spells of 3rd Level or lower
- 7 Spells of 2nd Level or lower
- Of those spells, two may come from any school, 7 must come from only Abjuration or Evocation

Then, go though the Spell List, sorting in descending order by Spell Level, and check off the highest category of spell level that each spell is valid for. As long as you don't exceed the limit for that slot, your list is valid. So for this list for a 13th level Eldritch Knight:

- 1 3rd level
- 8 2nd levels

We can prove it's valid.

- The 3rd level + 1 2nd level count for "2 3rd levels",
- and the remaining 2nd levels count for "7 2nd levels".

[image: Eldritch Knight Table]

#### Regarding their Spell School Restrictions

As best as I can determine, their spell school restrictions have no bearing on this table. The levels at which their non-restricted spells are handed out (3, 8, 14, and 20) are spaced out enough that it does not affect the sequencing of allocating their spells. So regardless of the level being considered, so long as they otherwise obey the restrictions set by this table, the unrestricted spells may be of any level.